# Did I calculate this indefinite integral correctly?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

The question:

**"$f'(x)=6x^{4.3}+5x^{-4.5}+6x^{0.6}$ and $f(1)=-11$. What is $f(x)$?"**

So I entered the problem in as $\int 6x^{4.3}+5x^{-4.5}+6x^{0.6}\,dx$
. This gave me $\frac{-1.42857}{x^(3.5)}+3.75x^{1.6}+1.13208x^{5.3}+c$

I then used $f(1)=-11$ and substituted it in as

$-11=\frac{-1.42857}{(1)^(3.5)}+3.75(1)^{1.6}+1.13208(1)^{5.3}+c$

And this gave me the constant to be $\frac{-1445351}{100000}$

The proper answer I am given however is

$\frac{6}{5.3}x^{5.3}-\frac{5}{3.5}x^{-3.5}+\frac{6}{1.6}x^{1.6}-11-\frac{6}{5.3}+\frac{5}{3.5}-\frac{6}{1.6}$

where did I go wrong and can someone show me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers are correct.The answer provided, didn't convert the fractions to their decimal expansions.

Also ,I read your statement "..So I entered the problem in as $∫6x4.3+5x−4.5+6x0.6dx$ . This gave me $−1.42857x(3.5)+3.75x1.6+1.13208x5.3+c$...".

Did you use calculator for it?If yes, then the answer provided hints that there was no use of it.

Comment: Ah okay thankyou

Comment: "Burden" suggests that using fractions is lazy, but the decimal expansions are only approximations. The fractions are exact.

Comment: @DavidK I understand,I have changed my wordings.

Comment: Yeah I used a calculator for the entire thing, just quicker (WolframAlpha btw). How can I get the fractions instead of the decimal approx.?

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX I meant to say that the answer provided in your book hints that you need not use the calculator at all(for converting them into deciaml approx.),as the answer provided is in fractions itself.

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX The provided answer suggests that you should apply the rule for integrating $x^n.$ When $n=4.3,$ for example, the integral is $\frac{1}{5.3}x^{5.3}.$ Therefore $\int 6x^{4.3}\,\mathrm dx = \frac{6}{5.3}x^{5.3} + C, $ and so forth. The only numerical simplification that was performed was $4.3 + 1 = 5.3$